# Raspberry Pico disappears and stays lost after loading UF2 file

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

I connected 2 Picos to my Mac and downloaded rp2-pico-20230426-v1.20.0uf2 from https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html. The Pico's disappear from the MAC's finder window and I can't get them to reappear without BOOTSEL and USB plug in. The file UF2 file doesn't show up after pressing BOOTSEL, so either I can't find the Pico's or I can find them without the necessary up loads. The Mac does complain of a disconnect, so I will try my windows computer and a proper Pi 3 to see if it is the system. I also tried the previous version 1.19 from https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico/.

Comment: My windows computer is doing the same thing. I am leaving it to run and see if time is the issues, but I did the same on my Mac and it didn't matter.

Comment: It's been a few months since I've reflashed mine, but as I remember, that's how it's supposed to work. From your first reference: *Drag and drop the MicroPython UF2 file onto the RPI-RP2 volume. Your Pico will reboot. You are now running MicroPython. You can access the REPL via USB Serial.*  When the Pico reboots, it does not appear as a flash drive - that only happens when BOOTSEL it presses. Use Mu or Thonny to see if the Pico presents as a serial port.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had used Thonny, but switched to Mu. The modes I had on that version didn't work, but I upgraded and on of the modes worked in the recent version of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the Mu editor and the version 1.2.0 with the RP2040 mode recognized the Pico. Previous versions had modes that were for micro python, but they had failed to recognize the Pico.